# How to make oneline string into new rows?

Tags: row, newline, newrow

s_n = ("Bob: Hello Sandy: How are you? Bob: Confused by a python problem"

print(s_n)

i want to make this string in multiple lines without using "\n".

Output to be :  Bob:

```
           Hello Sandy:

            How are you? ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s_n = ("""Bob: Hello
```

Sandy: How are you?
Bob: Confused by a python problem""""

print(s_n)

Output:
Bob: Hello
Sandy: How are you?
Bob: confused by a python problem

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem,because i need it to be print out in new lines one under another like in output i described,like in loop.

Comment: well you can add the linebreak by pressing enter and set your string in """[STRING]""" <- those will be translated in your print operation. Otherwise you have to use the \n linebreak operator.